# ASP.NET MVC data-attribute with auto-bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the sample ViewModel I get to the view:

```
public class CollectionOfStuffVM
{
    public string Element { get; set; }
    public bool IsPicked { get; set; }
}
```

This is asking for a Checkbox for multiple items, or a dropdown list if it is a single pick only. 
But, what if I am drawing this in a custom way?
Eg. below (inside a editor template):

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-picked="@Model.IsPicked">@Model.Element</a>
```

All the "data-picked" stuff is being handled by javascript when something is clicked.
So, how would it be possible to automatically bind these custom "controls"?

I guess there's some work that needs to be done, i'm just not sure, where. Do I need to create a custom Input? 
I know this auto bind would be doable with inputs, but i'm kinda avoding having to have hidden inputs being updated by Javascript.

Keep in mind this is just a simple example, the ViewModel is a bit more complex and it would be frustrating to have to build everything in Javascript to do an Ajax POST.

Comment: I've read thru this 3 times and for the life of me I can't understand what you want.  Is this not working somehow?  Specifically, what is it doing and what do you expect it to do?  Also, there isn't enough code here for me to be able to reproduce whatever you are getting.  Please edit in an MCVE and clear up what is going on and what you want.

Comment: automatically bind these custom "controls ; what does this mean ? can you be more elaborative about your expected behavior ?

Comment: You should use `RadioButtonFor` or `CheckBoxFor` hepler if you want easy binding. Eather way you should write custom js on your cliend or CustomModelBinder on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as two-way databinding when it comes to MVC. This is because, unlike something like a WPF application where everything runs on the same machine, a web application is disjointed, with server-side and client-side components.

If you want the data set by the client to be set back on the server, you have to post it to the server. If you handle that with a standard form, you must include some kind of input that has that value. If you do it with AJAX, you have a bit more freedom, as you don't need a physical HTML input element to hold the value, but you're still responsible for ensuring that the value makes it into the object you send to the server via AJAX.